# How to restrict user to take data back up of our application data through itunes sync process? through coding

Tags: iphone, backup, ipad

how do i restrict taking an application data backup using itunes sync..
its a requirement from my client that ....from application should not allow taking a backup of any files.

Can you please suggest me whether this is possible or not....
if yes can you please suggest me ways to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data security and if you're running on iOS 4.0 or greater, look at NSData's writeToFile:options:error:

Docs for option NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete state:
A hint to set the content protection attribute of the file when writing it out. In this case, the file is stored in an encrypted format and may be read from or written to only while the device is unlocked. At all other times, attempts to read and write the file result in failure.

This option set on a file stored in the cache directory *should* do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The caches directory will not be backed up. Find it using:

```
-(NSString*)dataPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

It will be flushed on a full restore. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html

Comment: I rescind my answer from before. mvds is correct, I thought that the "Caches" folder is backed up. In fact I was incorrect - "Caches" is not backed up at all to begin with.

Is it also the case that the "Caches" folder is not accessible via any other method while the device is connected to a computer? i.e. is it feasible that a user could make a backup of that folder themselves? If the question is a security-related one, this might factor into the decision either way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the iPod/iPhone/iPad is backed up automatically via iTunes, I would imagine that the only way to do that is to not store the files on the device to begin with - i.e. to make it a cloud service whereby the files can only be accessed when there is a network connection.

Comment: Ideally my application is about getting pdf's from client server and files will be saved in ipad, after a particular duration of time when user completes the reading of file server will send a requset to ipad client application to wipe off the pdf. at that time my code will take care about how to delete that file.
but mean time user should not be able to take a backup of those pdf files which stored in the application folder.
usinlg plist options i am disabling file sharing options, is there any othe way user can take a backup??????